# When using Crypto Subtle in Javascript to sign a message, do we need to sign the hash of the encoded message or the encoded message itself?

Tags: hash, cryptography, digital-signature, ecdsa, webcrypto-api

When using the browser built in Crypto Subtle in Javascript to sign a message, do we need to sign the hash of the encoded message or the encoded message itself?

The reason I ask is because as per the following:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15295/why-the-need-to-hash-before-signing-small-data

> If you do not hash the data before signing you cannot have one consistent signature algorithm, because you could only sign messages up to a certain size and if the size of the message gets too large you would need to hash. But that is not a good practice for signature schemes. More importantly, there are signature schemes which can easily be forged when the data is not hashed, such as RSA, see my answer here. In order to have security independent of the size of the signed message, we typically use this hash-then-sign paradigm, i.e., hash the plain message before performing signing operations on it, and thus the signature algorithm works for any size of the message and we do not really have to care about the message size.

However, when I look at the example code on Mozilla's site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign

It shows this example code:

```
function getMessageEncoding() {
  const messageBox = document.querySelector(".ecdsa #message");
  let message = messageBox.value;
  let enc = new TextEncoder();
  return enc.encode(message);
}

let encoded = getMessageEncoding();
let signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
  {
    name: "ECDSA",
    hash: { name: "SHA-384" },
  },
  privateKey,
  encoded
);
```

As you can see, Mozilla's example code signs the encoded message instead of hash of the encoded message. Are they doing it wrong?

The example code does specify `hash: { name: "SHA-384" }` as part of the `algorithm` parameter. So, is the `sign` function automatically doing the hash before signing it? Does that mean I can skip having to do the hash myself?

Comment: Yes, you can skip the explicit hashing. WebCrypto *implicitly* hashes the data during signing using the digest specified with the algorithm parameter (here SHA-384). Many libraries do this (to avoid signing unhashed data).

Comment: @Topaco is this documented somewhere? If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It is described indirectly by reference to FIPS-186 (in the WebCrypto docs) and to ANS X9.62 (in FIPS-186): *The signature generation process consists of: 1. Message digesting (...) Compute the hash value e = H(M) using the hash function...*. This is consistent with the [ECDSA example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign#ecdsa_2) from the Webrypto docs that passes the message (and not the message hash). And ultimately, this can be confirmed by verifying with another (reliable) library.

Comment: Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*WebCrypto* hashes the message implicitly, i.e. no explicit hashing may be performed, otherwise double hashing would occur. This also follows from the *WebCrypto* [documentation on ECDSA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign#ecdsa), which refers to [FIPS-186](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf) (sec. 6.4.1), where the hashing of the message is defined as part of the signing process.

Consistent with this is that in the [ECDSA example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign#ecdsa_2) of the *WebCrypto* documentation, the message and not the message hash is passed to `sign()`.

The ultimate check is the verification with a trusted library. Since *WebCrypto* supports the non-deterministic variant of ECDSA, a different signature is generated each time (even using the same key and message). Therefore, verification is only possible by successfully *verifying* the signature.
A possible library for verification is [*elliptic*](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic), which unlike *WebCrypto* does not implicitly hash, so that explicit hashing is required (which is also described in the documentation and examples). With *elliptic*, the signature generated with *WebCrypto* can be successfully verified, as the following code proves:

```js
(async () => {

    // Signing with WebCrypto: WebCrypto hashes implicitly:
    var messageStr = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    var messageAB = new TextEncoder().encode(messageStr);
    var keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: "ECDSA",namedCurve: "P-384"}, true, ["sign", "verify"]);
    var signatureAB = await window.crypto.subtle.sign({name: "ECDSA", hash: { name: "SHA-384" }}, keyPair.privateKey, messageAB); // pass the message
    var rawPublicKeyAB = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", keyPair.publicKey);

    // Verification with elliptic: elliptic does not hash implicitly, so explicit hashing is required:
    var ec = new elliptic.ec('p384');
    var publicKey = ec.keyFromPublic(ab2hex(rawPublicKeyAB), 'hex');
    var signatureHex = ab2hex(signatureAB);
    var signatureJO = { r: signatureHex.substr(0, 96), s: signatureHex.substr(96,96) };
    var msgHashHex = sha384(messageStr);                                                                                                                                                                                    // hash the message
    var verified = publicKey.verify(msgHashHex, signatureJO);                                                                                                                                       // pass the message hash
    console.log("Verification:", verified);

    function ab2hex(ab) { 
        return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(ab), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
    }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elliptic/6.5.4/elliptic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha512/0.8.0/sha512.min.js"></script>
```